# Is first value checked and second checkbox value post

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

```
function some_name() {
    if (document.getElementById('first').checked)      
        document.getElementById('second').checked=true; 
    else 
        document.getElementById('second').checked=false; 
    } 

                    <?php
                $idno       =   $vt->veriTemizle($_GET['idno']);
                $rest     =   $vt->sqlSorgu("Select * From rest ");
                foreach($vt->fetch_assocAll() as $rest){
                    echo '  
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option1[]"  onclick="some_name();" id="first" value="'.$rest["price"].'" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="extra[]"  onclick="some_name();" id="second" value="'.$rest["productname"].'-'.$rest["price"].' " />
                               ';
                }
            ?>
```

is a code I have been trying to do for a long time.
I have to select another one when the checkboxes listed above are clicked.

The first record listed is working, others are not

Comment: `<input type="hidden" onclick="some_name();"` - yeah, that makes sense (click handler for an _invisible_ element) … as does trying to set `checked` for a field of that type to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate IDs for all checkboxes like and solve the problem like this

```
<script>
function some_name( i) {
    console.log(i);
    if (document.getElementById('first'+i).checked)      
        document.getElementById('second'+i).checked=true; 
    else 
        document.getElementById('second'+i).checked=false; 
    } 
    </script>

                    <?php
                $row['price'] = 100;
                $row['productname'] = "ABC";
                $arr[] = $row;
                $row['price'] = 1001;
                $row['productname'] = "asd";
                $arr[] = $row;
                $row['price'] = 1002;
                $row['productname'] = "ABC2";
                $arr[] = $row;
                $row['price'] = 1003;
                $row['productname'] = "ABC1";
                $arr[] = $row;
                $i=0;
                foreach($arr as $rest){
                    echo '  
                    
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option1[]"  onclick="some_name('.$i.');" id="first'.$i.'" value="'.$rest["price"].'" />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="extra[]"  onclick="some_name('.$i.');" id="second'.$i.'" value="'.$rest["productname"].'-'.$rest["price"].' " />
                               ';
                               $i++;
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: You don’t _have to_, there’s other ways of selecting elements than just by ID.

Comment: @CBroe if you look at his code that's how he is dealing with other checkbox so it is better to just edit his code